# Do I need a special ODBC driver to connect Fedex Shipping Manager with a remotely hosted Magento database from Windows 7?

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

Trying to get my Fedex Ship Manager software connected to the remotely hosted magento database. I successfully connected the software to a zencart based database with the ODBC 3.51 Driver from mysql, but this driver does not get me connected with the magento database. 
I searched on google for information on Magento ODBC drivers and all I can find are companies selling them, not any information regarding if I actually need a special one or not. Trying to rule out if this is the cause or not. Nexcess tech support is not helpful, using all of the connection settings they told me to and still unable to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you do not need to have a special ODBC Driver to connect to Magento from Windows 7, the ODBC 3.51 driver from mysql will work. Ended up being a problem with the IP not being whitelisted for mysql access.